# WordPress is unable to install new plugins, connection aborted at MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache, segmentation-fault

My website is working perfectly until I am reading/changing website text content but whenever I am going to install a new plugin, I get the following message:

> Installation failed: Connection lost or the server is busy. Please try again later.

After several hours of investigation and tried different solutions, I checked the status of the MySQL host in phpmyadmin. I found every time I hit an install the new plugin button I have an aborted connection variable incremented. Everything is working before/after.

I am hosting a couple of my own websites and all have the same problem now.

I already tried existing solutions for the similar problems, like:

1. Disabling all plugins.
2. Switching to the default theme and renaming plugins folder to something else.
3. Replacing all files of wp-includes and wp-admin with a new copy of WordPress.
4. Repairing database.
5. Increasing memory in php.ini and wp-config.php

I also checked errors in apache and I have a segmentation fault every time I try to install a new plugin.

`[Mon Sep 24 04:43:03.726633 2018] [core:notice] [pid 18706] AH00051: child pid 18713 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Mon Sep 24 04:43:05.729536 2018] [core:notice] [pid 18706] AH00051: child pid 18714 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Mon Sep 24 04:43:07.731804 2018] [core:notice] [pid 18706] AH00051: child pid 18807 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Mon Sep 24 04:43:42.764302 2018] [core:notice] [pid 18706] AH00051: child pid 21719 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Mon Sep 24 04:43:43.766767 2018] [core:notice] [pid 18706] AH00051: child pid 26183 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Mon Sep 24 04:43:45.768930 2018] [core:notice] [pid 18706] AH00051: child pid 26246 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Mon Sep 24 04:50:31.167685 2018] [core:notice] [pid 18706] AH00051: child pid 18710 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
[Mon Sep 24 04:50:34.171751 2018] [core:notice] [pid 18706] AH00051: child pid 26523 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2`

[image]

Comment: Perhaps submit a ticket at your hosting provider's support portal? It might be a problem from their side since you have already exhausted the common solutions.

Comment: I am hosting my own websites.